# Ocaml Recursion

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Intersection [1;2;2;3;4;4;3][2;3] = [2;2;3;3]

There is something wrong with my code because it currently returns [2;2] since it won't match with t2, only h2, does anyone have any suggestions on the direction I should be thinking in to change this?

```
let rec intersection (l1: int list) (l2: int list) : int list =
  begin match l1, l2 with
    | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> if h1=h2 then h1::intersection t1 l2 
                                 else intersection t1 l2
    | _ -> []
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that both of your recursive calls pass l2, the entire second list. This means that `h2` is always going to refer to the same element, the first element of the second list. This explains why you're only getting matches on `2` in your example.

You need to look deeper into the second list.

As a side comment, this function isn't easily represented as a single recursive function IMHO. It might be better to think of having two separate sub-operations. In particular, you're interested in whether an int appears in `l2` and this is its own separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment! (duly noted)